# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + n^2}}$ Convergence

Tags: calculus

I'm currently evaluating the sum

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + n^2}}$$

My strategy is writing the first few terms and seeing what sum I know they are similar to. If I do this I get:

$$n=1\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < 1$$
$$n=2\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} < \frac{1}{2}$$
$$n=3\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{10}} < \frac{1}{3}$$
$$n=4\rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{17}} < \frac{1}{4}$$

and so on.

My thought was (never mind an easier method, I just wondered if) to make this argument: you can make the difference between the members (n=1, n=2, ..) of this infinite sum and the harmonic series as small as you want, provided you pick $$n \geq N$$ for some $N$ which will depend on the difference of course. Formally I guess I want to say:

$$|a_n - b_n| < \epsilon$$ $$\forall n \geq N, \epsilon > 0$$
if we call $a_n$ the members of the harmonic series and $b_n$ the members of the infinite sum above.

Thus I can conclude that the sum diverges. Is there a mistake in my argument or have I (informally, of course) proved that this sum diverges?

Comment: exactly. that's why i made the argument. is this a valid proof though?

Comment: Certainly a sensible line of attack.  And your reasoning is correct.  For large $n$ we have $\frac 1{\sqrt {1+n^2}}\approx \frac 1n$.  However, showing that $a_n<b_n$ is not a good way to show that $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: You might try to prove the following version of the comparison test...for positive $\{a_n\}$, $\{b_n\}$ if $\lim \frac {a_n}{b_n}=1$ then $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\sum b_n$ converges.

Comment: but is it, not only convincing, but shouldn't this be a proof?

Comment: I made a few edits to your post, Christopher (particularly, in the succession of n in your list.)  I hope all is what you intended.

Comment: Well, I don't see a complete proof here.  After all, let $a_n=\frac 1n$ and let $b_n=0$.  Then I can make the difference $|a_n-b_n|$ as small as desired, but that doesn't imply that the sum  $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: If I did, it would be?
For the comparison test, couldn't I just say that the $limit{\frac{a_n}{b_n} = \limit{\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ thus reversing the argument, making this theorem useless? I feel like I'm missing something, don't mean to be rude

Comment: Not following.  Yes, if $\lim \frac {a_n}{b_n}=1$ then you have a symmetry between $a_n,b_n$.  So what?

Comment: So then if lim an/bn = 1 then lim bn/an = 1, thus if $\sum a_n$ converges $\sum b_n$ converges but also vice versa. I don't get it?

Comment: What's the problem?  You have said it exactly.  If the limit holds then either both of them diverge or both of them converge.  It's a great result!

Comment: Note:  you don't need the limit to be $1$ (though it is in your case).  All you need to invoke the theorem is that the limit exists, call it $L$, and that $0<L<\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I agree. I see what you mean. So this would also imply that an diverges if bn diverges, am I right? ( if lim an/bn = 1)

Comment: Absolutely!  and again, you don't need $L=1$.  you just need $0<L<\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that
$$
2n^2=n^2+n^2\geq1+n^2
$$
Then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}n}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit comparison test. Note that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}}=\frac{1}{n}\tag{1}.
$$
Indeed, 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1/\sqrt{1+n^2}}{1/n}
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n^2}}{\sqrt{1+n^2}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+n^{-2}}}=1.
$$
By (1) since the harmonic series diverges, the series in question diverges as well.